# Xamarin & Sybase Ultralite

Tags: xamarin, sybase, ultralite

**Xamarin** give us the possibility to write portable apps in Android, IOs and also Windows phone.
**Sybase ultralite** give us the possibiility to use his DB on all this os.

Does anyone can help me on understand how to use Sybase Ultralite db on a **Xamarin portable** app?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason that you do now want to use [SQLite](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/)?

Comment: Absolutely yes! Sybase Ultralite gives a really useful system to automatically syncronize the remote db with the local db (MobiLink).

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Have you checked out [this article](https://jglavery.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/creating-an-xamarin-android-binding-for-sybase-ultralite/) talking about doing bindings for Sysbase? That is an old article and will be fairly involved. Another option might be to us Azure's Mobile Services which has Xamarin Components that can be downloaded and installed and also offers automatic offline data synchronization. An article about that can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data/)

Comment: unfortunately our customer need precisely this kind of solution...